# Einstein Scoring for Custom Object

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

We want to have Einstein Scoring for our custom *Job* object. And we would like it to be like *Lead Scoring* on the screenshot:

[image]

We plan to develop a custom Lightning Component for that purpose.

I understand how to get such type of score with *Einstein Prediction Builder* and show it on the Lightning Component. But I don't understand where can I get the *Top Positives* and *Top Negatives* sections data from.

How to access that Top Positives / Top Negatives data?